# MissingMethodException w/ Method present -> nerve-racking VS2010 bug?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, missingmethodexception

For two days now I have a really pesky problem with VS 2010 (SP 1).
My solution consists of 1 Azure project with 4 roles with each 1 instance. Each one of them executes a configuration change at one of the first lines to set the date format for the ServiceStack.Text JSON Serializer.

```
JsConfig.DateHandler = JsonDateHandler.ISO8601;
```

One would think there isn't much that can go wrong here, but somehow my VS thinks otherwise..
If I execute a Clean+Rebuild, the solution works just fine. If I stop the debugging (or some other exception ends the debug run), every further debug run will stop at this line and throw a MissingMethodException [image: thrown exception] .

If I do a Clean+Rebuild again, it works for exactly 1 run and then the exception gets thrown again.
Obviously the method can't just vanish, but I am out of ideas about what could be the source of this problem and it just destroys my efficiency to Clean+Rebuild after E V E R Y single change.

The previous ServiceStack.Text version did indeed not have this method (and yes, I used the previous version as of a few days ago), but I removed every single bit of it. I even looked at typeof(JsConfig).Assembly via QuickWatch to confirm that it loaded the latest version, which it did, so I can't imagine how the previous version could be responsible.

Actions which I already tried but didn't change anything:

- Removed the .suo
- Deactivated AV and SearchProtocolHost (maybe they locked the file or something)
- Removed everything ServiceStack.Text-related via NuGet and reinstalled it in every (using) project
- Restarted VS2010 half a billion times
- Rebooted
- Looked for something obvious in Sysinternals Process Monitor

Btw. I don't think this problem is really related to the ServiceStack.Text Library, but obviously I can't know that for sure.

Comment: I got the same MissingMethod exception (@ JsConfig.DateHandler = JsonDateHandler.DCJSCompatible;) when I host my code in a service. But running it in a unittest it runs fine everytime. I feel your frustation... Please update if you figure this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problems (see my comment), but after a upgrade to the latest version of Servicesstack.Text, and the problem has gone.

Larsi

Comment: oops, only saw your comment, not your answer. But you are right, I did an upgrade for ServiceStack.Text, too, so that may also be the reason why it worked afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is fixed but I don't know exactly what did it.

I moved my TFS workspace to a different drive, which (didn't know, thought it would just move everything over to new drive) just got the latest version from the repository and afterwards it seems to have fixed it. 
So the problem must lie in those files that are being excluded from TFS source control. It can't be the .suo because I deleted it multiple times, but it also can't be those files that are being overwritten with each build ("Clean" deleted them already), so that should not leave a lot of files left.
Hope that helps at least a little bit.